# Memory peaks again shortly thereafter Erlang gc (fullsweep)?

Tags: garbage-collection, erlang

Memory will drop immediately when Erlang fullsweep, but for a short time it goes up to the original peak and then it goes down.

When I stop loop for create memory after cast gc to TestPid for 3 minutes or more. Memory goes up to the original peak and then goes down after I start the loop.

How does it work?
[image: major collection memory change pic]

This is my simple test code.

ts.erl

```
-module(ts).
-behaviour(gen_server).
%% API
-export([
    start/0,
    stop/0,
    gc/0, loop_cnt/1
]).
%% gen_server callbacks
-export([init/1, handle_call/3, handle_cast/2, handle_info/2,
    terminate/2, code_change/3]).

-define(SERVER, ?MODULE).
-define(BASE_CNT, 10000).
-define(ONE_LOOP_CNT, 200).
-record(state, {loop_cnt = 0, one_loop_cnt = 0}).


start() ->
    gen_server:start({local, ?SERVER}, ?MODULE, [], []).


stop() ->
    gen_server:cast(?SERVER, stop).

gc() ->
    gen_server:cast(?SERVER, gc).

loop_cnt(Cnt) when is_number(Cnt) ->
    gen_server:cast(?SERVER, {loop_cnt, Cnt}).


init([]) ->
    io:format("start mem ~n"),
    erlang:send_after(1, self(), start_add_mem),
    {ok, #state{one_loop_cnt = ?ONE_LOOP_CNT}, 0}.


handle_call(_Req, _From, State) ->

    {noreply, State}.

handle_cast(start_add_mem, State) ->
    io:format("cast start_add_mem~n"),
    {noreply, State};

handle_cast(gc, State) ->
    io:format("garbage_info beforegc ~w ~n", [erlang:process_info(self(), garbage_collection)]),
    {Us, _} = timer:tc(erlang, garbage_collect, [self()]),
    io:format("do_gc cost:~wms ~n", [Us / 1000]),
    {noreply, State};

handle_cast({loop_cnt, Cnt}, State) ->
    io:format("set loop_cnt ~w ~n", [Cnt]),
    {noreply, State#state{one_loop_cnt = Cnt}};

handle_cast(stop, State) ->
    {stop, normal, State}.


handle_info(start_add_mem, #state{loop_cnt = Cnt, one_loop_cnt = OneLoopCnt} = State) ->
    erlang:send_after(1000, self(), start_add_mem),
    StartCnt = Cnt rem 100,
    case Cnt rem 30 =:= 0 of
        true ->
            io:format("garbage_info ~w ~n", [erlang:process_info(self(), garbage_collection)]);
        false ->
            ok
    end,
    do_add_mem(StartCnt, OneLoopCnt),
    try
        {_, L} = erlang:process_info(self(), garbage_collection),
        case lists:keyfind(minor_gcs, 1, L) of
            false ->
                io:format("gc find mingcs error~w ~n", [erlang:process_info(self(), garbage_collection)]);
            {_, GcCount} ->
                case GcCount =:= 0 of
                    true ->
                        io:format("mabay_trigger gc ~w ~n", [erlang:process_info(self(), garbage_collection)]);
                    _ ->
                        ok
                end
        end
    catch _A:_B ->
        io:format("gc print error ~w ~w ~n", [erlang:process_info(self(), garbage_collection), {_A, _B}]),
        ok
    end,
    {noreply, State#state{loop_cnt = Cnt + 1}};

handle_info(_Req, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.

terminate(_Reason, _State) ->
    ok.

code_change(_OldVsn, State, _Extra) ->
    {ok, State}.

%%%===================================================================
%%% Internal functions
%%%===================================================================

do_add_mem(StartCnt, OneLoopCnt) ->

    lists:foreach(
        fun(I) ->
            Dict = dict:new(),
            NewDict = lists:foldl(
                fun(J, AccDict) ->
                    dict:store(J, I, AccDict)
                end, Dict, lists:seq(1, OneLoopCnt)),
            L = lists:seq(1, OneLoopCnt),
            case random:uniform() > 0.5 of
                true ->
                    erlang:put({tm, I}, {NewDict, L});
                false ->
                    erlang:put({tm, I}, undefined)
            end
        end, lists:seq(StartCnt * ?BASE_CNT, StartCnt * ?BASE_CNT + ?BASE_CNT)),
    ok.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that peak is the GC creating a new heap while running a major GC, the second valley is when the previous heap is freed.

Taking into account that each process executes its GC at different times and that you usually don't have processes with a 5GB heap, you won't (or shouldn't) notice it in a production system.

The documentation about [erlang's generational GC](https://erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/GarbageCollection.html#generational-garbage-collection) is really detailed, I think it deserves a careful read.

Also, you can use [`trace`](http://erlang.org/documentation/doc-11.0-rc3/erts-11.0/doc/html/erlang.html#trace-3) to get messages when a GC starts or ends:
`erlang:trace(Pid, true, [monotonic_timestamp, garbage_collection])` or use `process_info`'s `total_heap_size` and `heap_size`.